# How to parse HTML into text in Java

Tags: java, html, text

I have a program to connect to the internet and read the file. But its result is always in html.. how can i possible turn it into normal text..

here's the code:

```
package urlconnectionreader;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Hi!");
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        yc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
        yc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();

    }
}
```

--EDITED--

I want to get rid of html tags in its output.

Comment: Uhm, HTML _is_ text ultimately. What is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: i mean, i want to display it without html tags.

Answer (score 0):

you could use  [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) very easy well documented and optimized for getting and parsing html file.

Answer (score 0):

your code is work fine, the System.out.println(inputLine); did print html in text, you can assign the output as string so that you can use it later.[image]

like this:

```
    package urlconnectionreader;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class URLConnectionReader {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Hi!");
            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.sarawak.gov.my/");
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            yc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/html");
            yc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html, application/html");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            String strtempHtml = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                strtempHtml = strtempHtml+inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
            String noHTMLString = strtempHtml.replaceAll("\\<.*?>",""); 
            System.out.println(noHTMLString ); //html tag removed
        }

}
```

Comment: i mean, i want to get rid of html tags.

Comment: String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup for this. http://jsoup.org/

To get the entire document as an object model,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.oracle.com/").get();
```

If you want just to parse whatever the html you get in your code,

```
String html = "";
while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    html = html + inputLine; // better use StringBuilder instead.
}

String text = Jsoup.parse(html).body().text();
```